# /ɫ/ interacting with /ɨ/ in Russian: Pharyngealized, uvularized or velarized?

Tags: phonetics, russian

In the Russian language:

- /ɫ/ is pharyngealized
- /ɨ/ velarizes the preceding consonant.

In words such as `лысый`, /ˈɫɨsɨj/, is ɫ velarized, uvularized or pharyngealized?

I was unable to find any resources on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Natallia Litvin. "An Ultrasound Investigation of Secondary Velarization in Russian" (2014).

"To summarize, our study shows that Russian non-palatalized consonants [f, l, s, ʂ, x] are
not pharyngealized. The Russian non-palatalized [f] and [l] exhibit secondary velarization,
while [s] and [ʂ] can display either uvularization or velarization as a function of individual variation. Both secondary uvularization and velarization, however, perform a single phonological function: differentiation of non-palatalized/hard consonants and their
palatalized/soft counterparts".

Answer (score 4):

Here are some resources. Proctor (2009) [Gestural Characterization of a Phonological Class: the Liquids](http://mproctor.net/docs/diss/proctor09_liquids.pdf) talks about the question, citing three pertinent articulatory studies (Skalozub, Larisa Georgievna. 1963. *Palatogrammy i rentgenogrammy soglasnykh fonem russkogo literaturnogo iazyka*, vol. 3. Kiev: Izdatel’stvo Kievskogo universiteta; Bolla, Kalman. 1981. *A conspectus of Russian speech sounds*, vol. Bd. 32. Koln: B̈ohlau. and [Kedrova et al. (2008)](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/5326361_Magnetic_Resonance_investigation_of_palatalized_stop_consonants_and_spirants_in_Russian). The latter study, however, does not study /l/ specifically, and does not assign specific phonological labels to hard and soft consonants.

The literature does contain all three claims. As far as I know, there is no definitive articulatory study which compares Russian dark *l*  with a known pharyngealized /l/. Proctor *models* dark /l/ with "dorsal retraction and raising towards the velarized tongue body constriction location". I would also recommend [Esling et al 2019](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/voice-quality/voice-quality/061C65B97CE5AF9C13CAB032C4BC9731), because numerous ideas about back-of-tract articulations are based on an inadequate model of "larynx" (they argue that the "larynx" is bigger than traditionally thought).

Comment: Hi, yours was a great and detailed answer however I since the answer I was precisely looking for appeared I need to remove the "accept answer" so please don't be feel bad.